# When do you use *ngIf="isProductSearchEmpty" or [style.display]="displayProduct"?

Tags: angular

Some times I do **NOT** know when to use `*ngIf="isProductSearchEmpty"` or `[style.display]="displayProduct"`.

```
<div *ngIf="isProductSearchEmpty">
  <div class="not-found searchStr">
  "{{searchStr}}" not found..
  </div>
  <rb-categories></rb-categories>
</div>
```

I have the option to use:

```
<div [style.display]="displayProduct">
  <div class="not-found searchStr">
  "{{searchStr}}" not found..
  </div>
  <rb-categories></rb-categories>
</div>
```

In *product-list.component.ts*, `isProductSearchEmpty` is either true or false and `displayProduct` is either none or block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ngIf :

> Conditionally includes a template based on the value of an expression.

It will add and remove the element from the DOM. So when you use with *ngIf you should consider that your template rendering may change for other elements.
Additionally, `*ngIf` can be used to display a whole template with 'ngIf -then else' syntax. It's more used when applied to a 'big' block of markup or when there is a else if condition going on.

`[style.display]` will only trigger the css property 'display' change. It's more to change the display property of the element.

Often `[hidden]` is used in lieu of `*ngIf` which takes the reverse logic and doesn't remove the element from the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Most often you will want to use  `ngIf` as it correctly processes (adds or removes) child host views (components) and embedded views in the component view. It means:

- updating the `ViewChild` and `ViewChildren` queries
- triggering `ngOnDestroy`

Here is an example:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    queries: [],
    template: `
        <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
        <div *ngIf="false">
            <a-comp></a-comp>
        </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
    @ViewChildren(AComponent) children;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.children.length); // 0
    }
}
```

Whereas `display.none` simply doesn't renderer DOM nodes, but the child elements are still processed by Angular:

```
template: `
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    <div [style.display]="'none'">
        <a-comp></a-comp>
    </div>
`,
```

and the length is now  `1`:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.children.length); // 1
}
```

The `ngOnDestroy` is also not triggered for the `a-comp` when it's being hidden and it now thinks that it's still exists.

I would say that `[style.display]="'none'"` can be safely used when the element it's used on doesn't house child components or embedded views created using `ViewContainerRef`.